# C# Using Excel Search Function

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto

I am in the process of porting a VBA procedure to a C# project.  I am close to having everything completely finished, but I have 2 errors remaining.  This is the syntax:

```
public static void ExcelPort()
{
object What = "*";
object After = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "IV65536");
object LookIn = Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues;
object LookAt = Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart;
object SearchOrder = Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows;
Excel.XlSearchDirection SearchDirection = Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext;
object MatchCase = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object MatchByte = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object SearchFormat = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

currentsheet = (Excel._Worksheet)(xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet);
activeworkbook = (Excel.Workbook)xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;
int lastrow = 0;

foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in activeworkbook.Worksheets)
{
    if (usedrows = (double)xlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheet.Cells) != 0)
    {
        lastrow = sheet.Cells.Find(What,After,LookIn,LookAt,SearchOrder,SearchDirection,MatchCase,MatchByte,SearchFormat);
    }
    else
    {
        lastrow = 1;
    }
}
}
```

**Error List & Lines**

```
//This  line throws an error
(double)xlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheet.Cells) != 0

//Error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'double'

//This line throws an error        sheet.Cells.Find(What,After,LookIn,LookAt,SearchOrder,SearchDirection,MatchCase,MatchByte,SearchFormat)

//Error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range' to 'int'
```

Comment: @stuartd - if I alter the line to if (usedrows = (double)(xlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheet.Cells)) != 0) I still get the same error

Comment: @stuartd - double usedrows;

Comment: Find() returns a reference to the matching cell (if it exIsts) or Nothing/Null if no match is found.  `lastrow = sheet.Cells.Find(...).Row` is probably what you want here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first error, this is simply incorrect C# syntax and has nothing to do with Excel:

> ```
> if (usedrows = (double)xlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheet.Cells) != 0)
> ```

It's complaining about trying to assign the result of the `!= 0` comparison, which is a `bool`, to `usedrows`, which is a `double`.  Use parentheses to compare the result of the assignment to 0:

```
if ((usedrows = (double)xlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheet.Cells)) != 0)
```

The second error is that `.Find` returns an `Excel.Range`, not an `int`.  In VBA it will call the default member of a reference type if you're assigning it to a non-reference type. C# doesn't do that - you have to make an explicit call. The default member of a `Range` is `.Value`, but by the context I'm assuming that you're looking for the row number:

```
var found = sheet.Cells.Find(What, After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, 
    SearchDirection, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat);
lastrow = found != null ? found.Row : 1;
```

Comment: @Comintrn - you are correct with your assumption, I am looking for the row number so I can add 1 to it, then add a "totals" row.

Comment: On your line lastrow = found != null ? found.Row : 1; -- I get an error of Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'

Comment: @StarsFlyFreeFromCozyNights - I can't replicate that error at all. Did you change the declaration `int lastrow = 0;`?